# using transformToUni

Tags: vert.x, mutiny

being relatively new to mutiny I am having a little difucauly wrapping my head around the following:
given the following working code:

```
public Uni<Long> getCounterValue() {
        return  this.vertx.sharedData().getCounter(COUNTER_NAME).onItem().transformToUni(counter->counter.get());
    }
```

I simply want to return a Uni where the Long is a current state of a vert.x shared counter.

what is hard for me is that counter.get() actually already returns a Uni so I feel like I am doing a transformToUni on something that already has the return time I need.

I hope I explained myself. like I said, the code works but its hard for me to get the why... maybe there's also another way, more self explanatory, to achieve this?

(BTW, I looked at the guides but still I am confused)

your comments are appreciated.
thanks

Comment: You could rewrite this as: `return this.vertx.sharedData().getCounter(COUNTER_NAME).chain(Counter::get);`

Comment: Thanks but this is just syntactic sugar. My issue is of understanding... I don't 'get' why if the counter returns already a uni of long I still have to transform it to a uni.... This is what I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Are you confusing `transform` and `transformToUni`?  How would like to write the code?

Comment: I am a little confused with the fact that I transform to uni something that already is a uni. I am sure there's a logical way to explain this but I can't find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the explanation is that you need a new Uni that's aware of the event emitted by `getCounter` and that will call `counter.get()`. Or, in general, a new `Uni` that knows what to do with the result of the previous one and makes sure that everything happens in the right order at subscription.

Let's take a simpler example, we have three `Uni`:

```
Uni<?> first = Uni.createFrom,().item(1).invoke(System.out::print);
Uni<?> second = Uni.createFrom().item(2).invoke(System.out::print);
Uni<?> third = first.chain(() -> second);
```

- If you subscribe `first`, it will print `1`.
- If you subscribe `second`, it will print `2`.
- If you subscribe `third`, it will print `12`.

These are three different Uni, emitting different events at different times.

What you are suggesting is to return `second` when `transformToUni` (or `chain`) is called to create `third`. But, in that case, the result would be different from what we want.